# winappdriver based java selenium automation stops working after some time

Tags: java, selenium, testng, appium, winappdriver

I want to run a java based automation test (using testng) on a windows application 24*7. The code is working fine but after some time the winappdriver responds very slowly and selenium's basic operation like clicking element is taking a lot of time unless I restart my windows machine. WinAppDriver gets stuck on the state shown in image.
[winappdriver state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWGP8.png)

I tried `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` so that if it could not find an element within 2 seconds then it should throw an exception but it is not working. I just want that if it is taking too long to perform an operation then it should throw an exception and my Retryanalyzer will restart the test but I dont know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        do action
        CustomReporter.log("\n action");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        call reset method
        CustomReporter.log("\n reset");
    }
```

But using implicitlyWait is not a very good approach in general

Did you check memory usage? It would be better to check it

Comment: The issue is with winappdriver. It has memory leak issue...do you know if there is anyway we can avoid memory leaks of windows application driver ?